# BeautifulSoup Remove all html tags except for those in whitelist such as "img" and "a" tags with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Given some html code, how can I remove all the tags, keep the text and img and a tags?
For example, I have

```
<div><script bla bla></script><p>Hello all <a href ="xx"></a> <img rscr="xx"></img></p></div>
```

I want to keep

```
Hello to <a href ="xx"></a> <img rscr="xx"></img>
```

Is there something implemented in BeautifulSoup or Python?

Thanks

Comment: In terms of security a whitelist is best !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select all of the descendant nodes by accessing the [`.descendants` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants).

From there, you could iterate over all of the descendants and filter them based on the `name` property. If the node doesn't have a `name` property, then it is likely a text node, which you want to keep. If the `name` property is `a` or `img`, then you keep it as well.

```
# This should be the wrapper that you are targeting
container = soup.find('div')
keep = []

for node in container.descendants:
  if not node.name or node.name == 'a' or node.name == 'img':
    keep.append(node)
```

Here is an alternative where all the filtered elements are used to create the list directly:

```
# This should be the wrapper that you are targeting
container = soup.find('div')

keep = [node for node in container.descendants
        if not node.name or node.name == 'a' or node.name == 'img']
```

Also, if you don't want strings that are empty to be returned, you can trim the whitespace and check for that as well:

```
keep = [node for node in container.descendants
        if (not node.name and len(node.strip())) or
           (node.name == 'a' or node.name == 'img')]
```

Based on the HTML that you provided, the following would be returned:

```
> ['Hello all ', <a href="xx"></a>, <img rscr="xx"/>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

html = '''<div><script bla bla></script><p>Hello all <a href ="xx"></a> <img rscr="xx"></img></p></div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.div.text, soup.div.find_next('a'), soup.div.find_next('img')
```

out:

```
('Hello all  ', <a href="xx"></a>, <img rscr="xx"/>)
```

When the next element is tag's descendent, there is a shortcut:

```
soup.div.text, soup.div.a, soup.div.img
```

out:

```
('Hello all  ', <a href="xx"></a>, <img rscr="xx"/>)
```

1. when you use bs4's parser, 'img' tag will be self-closed tag
2. You can aways use `find_next` to get next element in the DOM

Comment: what if I had "<div><script bla bla></script><p>Hello all <a href ="xx"></a> <img scr="xx"><img scr="sdfgsdfgx"><img scr="xdgsgfsdfgdgdf4x"></p></div>"??? Your code only gives the first tag found it encounters...the string was only an example, I need to parse an entire webpage.